# SQL Server : detect if a column changes depending on condition

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am developing a SQL Server based async browser chat with ASP.NET MVC in C#. My project consists of a web project, a winforms application and a database of course. In my database, I have a table called **User** with a DateTime property named **LastLogin** and another boolean property named **isOnline**. I want to set **isOnline** to false, if (**LastLogin** + 15sec =< DateTime.Now), so 15seconds is the timeout. What is the best solution to solve this problem in your opinion?
Do you have suggestions for a better title?

Comment: 15 seconds seems like an awful short 'logged-in session'.  Are you asking how do you regularly check the DB and update isOnline behind the scenes?

Comment: the first thought I had was a trigger (puke), but it'll only run on login. Therefore it'll never update to "offline"

Comment: of course I know about Session in MVC but I'd like to do my own for education purposes. here are some of my methods: BeginSession(), KeepAlive(), Deauth()...I thought about a method in my winforms app which will update all user records (LastLogin + 15sec =< DateTime.Now) or how about a stored procedure which will do the job? is that possible? I have no experience with SP

Comment: I solved the problem with a winforms method (updating the database) each 15sec

Answer (score 0):

First off, checkout something like the [SignalR source](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/tree/master/samples) to see how they're doing it. Second, I'd look into doing it via Session && Logout.

In your Global.asax

```
void Session_End(Object sender, EventArgs E) {
    // update the database with "offline"
}
```

In your logout code

```
protected void LogOut_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // logout
    // update database with "offline"
    // redirect to public page of your choosing.
}
```